# Как экранировать кавычки в строке шелла?

Tags: excel, vba, visual-basic, ms-word

есть шелл архивации папки

```
Shell (sWinRarAppPath & " A -ep -df " & folderForMails & strName & ".rar " & strFolder)
```

переменная strFolder содержит название папки с пробелами. нужно чтобы в шелл попадало "название папки"

пытаюсь сделать так, ничего не получается, т.к. закрывает переменную. В результате в данном месте выводит & strFolder &.

```
Shell (sWinRarAppPath & " A -ep -df " & folderForMails & strName & ".rar " & """ & strFolder & """)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полезная привычка - собрать сначала команду в строковой переменной, а потом её выполнять (и Debug.Print - для проверки):

```
strCommand = sWinRarAppPath & " A -ep -df " & folderForMails & strName & ".rar " & """" & strFolder & """"
REM Debug.Print strCommand
Shell strCommand
```

И кавычки надо считать тщательнее.

Ещё лучше - вместо удвоения вставлять кавычку явно с использованием CHR(34):

```
strCommand = sWinRarAppPath & " A -ep -df " & folderForMails & strName & ".rar " & CHR(34) & strFolder & CHR(34)
REM Debug.Print strCommand
Shell strCommand
```

Comment: Работает. За совет отдельное спасибо, не знал, как проверять собранную команду.